# How to Identify exact x and y axis of Black Dots in Image?

Tags: android, image-processing, graphics

I am trying to create a simple class `DotedImage`, its function will be to store an image from `R.drawable.x` in the form of **Bitmap** and this class automatically fill `dots` list of objects as **Point**.

I have studies these projects from [stanford implementation](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/) but was way too advanced.

Here are the test images:

[image]

or

[image]

Here my starting class:

```
public class DotedImage {
    private final int imageResourceId;
    private Bitmap myImage;
    private List<Point> dots;
    private final Context context;

    public Bitmap getMyImage() {
        return myImage;
    }
    public void setMyImage(Bitmap myImage) {
        this.myImage = myImage;
    }
    public List<Point> getDots() {
        return dots;
    }
    public void setDots(List<Point> dots) {
        this.dots = dots;
    }
    public DotedImage(Context context,int imageResourceId) {
        this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), imageResourceId);
        identifyBlackDots();
    }

    public void identifyBlackDots(){
        // setting up dots Lists with each black Point
        // object in Image
    }

}
```

How can I write identifyBlackDots for achieving my goal in Android?

Comment: i cannot add more links in question so : here is the customView where i will then give Dots list to further processing : https://gist.github.com/lecho/4332335#file-connectdotsview-java

Comment: @BalajiR yes these are very good answers for image processing but problem is all are in other languages not java/android , isn't there any way to achieve such task in android ?

Comment: Opencv is available for java/android! If you want to implement by your own ! Read its source code & try to implement by your own!